# POST an issue to GitHub API with angular returns 404 HTTP Status

Tags: angular, api, github

I am trying to add an issue to a GitHub repository via the GitHub API, but I keep getting the Status 404 - Not Found as a return. I'm using OAuth Authentication, so the access token is sent with the URL.

Here where I send the requisition:

```
return this.http.post(`${URL_API}/${username}/${repository}/issues?access_token=${accessToken}`, issue);
```

On the requisitioning body, I'm sending the issue which is a JSON structure:

```
{"title":"Issue title","body":"Issue Body"}
```

That's the response I'm getting from the server:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "https://api.github.com/repos/username/repository/iss…ss_token=accessToken"
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Anyone out there knows the answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you'll be sending `access_token` as a QueryParam and not as an `Authorization` Header?

Answer (score 0):

It specifies [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), that:

> Requests that require authentication will return 404 Not Found, instead of 403 Forbidden, in some places.

Which sorta explains the error you're getting.

For some reason, in your case, it's not registering the `access_token` that you're sending as a Query Param as specified [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-as-a-parameter).

You can try sending it as a Header instead as suggested [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/#oauth2-token-sent-in-a-header).

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

...

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': `token ${accessToken}`
  })
};

return this.http.post(`${URL_API}/${username}/${repository}/issues`, issue, httpOptions);
```

Comment: I tried and I'm still getting the same error. Looks like my token it's not being sent booth as a header or a query param. 

In the API documentation says that "Any user with pull access to a repository can create an issue.". 

I believe that the token I'm sending it's supposed to granting the pull access, right?